# Read in all excel lines and columns and print them on a .rtf document?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to read in a whole spreadsheet with different values in columns and lines. Furthermore, I want to create a new .rtf document, where I fill in those data. How would you iterate over the whole spreadsheet until the first column is empty and print this into the new document?
I would appreciate every kind of feedback.

my current code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteToFile()
    On Error GoTo Mistakemark

    Dim targetData As String
    Dim Line As Integer

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    targetData = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="AVL (*.rtf), *.rtf", InitialFileName:="AVL.rtf")

    Open targetData For Output As #1

    For Line= 1 To 19
        Print #1, Cells(Line, 2).Value
    Next Line

    Close #1

    Exit Sub

Mistakemark:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub WriteToFile()
    Dim targetData As String
    Dim Line As Integer

    On Error GoTo Mistakemark

    targetData = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="AVL (*.rtf), *.rtf", InitialFileName:="AVL.rtf")

    Open targetData For Output As #1

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For Line = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            MsgBox .Range(.Cells(Line, 2), .Cells(Line, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Address
            Print #1, Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(Line, 2), .Cells(Line, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value)), ",")
        Next
    End With

    Close #1

    Exit Sub

Mistakemark:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get an error saying: "not a valid procedure." Maybe this correlates with my version of excel (2007).

Comment: Hello, for some reason the code does not iterate over column "A". Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You’d better post a new question with all relevant info (data layout) and code attempts

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already did, but the answer: "change(.Range(.Cells(.Line, 2) to (.Range(.Cells(.Line, 1 " does not help, because I get the message "incompatible types". So I thought you would be the best person to ask for advice.

Comment: Please give me the link to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129178/iterate-over-whole-excel-file